# Can we put IBOutlets in a category?

Tags: ios, objective-c

Since the `ViewController`'s code is getting too large, I was wondering how to split the code into multiple files. Here's the problem I ran into:

```
// In the original .m file, there are bunch of outlets in the interface extension.
@interface aViewController()
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIView *contentView1;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIView *contentView2;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIView *contentView3;
@end
```

I want to split the file into 3 categories, according to three different views.

```
// In category aViewController+contentView1.m file
@interface aViewController()
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIView *contentView1;
@end
```

If I delete the original `contentView1` outlet, however, it doesn't work.

**Question**
Why do I have to keep the `contentView1` outlet in the original `.m` file?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

An Objective-C ***`category`*** doesn't allow you to add additional properties to a class, only methods. Thereby, you aren't allowed to add additional `IBOutlet`s within a `category`. A category is denoted similar to `@interface aViewController (MyCategoryName)` (note the name given inside the parentheses).

You can, however, add additional properties within a ***`class extension`***. A `class extension` is denoted with the same name as the original class followed by `()`. In your code example, both lines referring to `@interface aViewController()` actually declare a `class extension` (not a `category`), regardless of which `header` file they're actually in.

Furthermore, you are allowed to create multiple class extensions across several different headers. The trick is that you need to import these correctly.

In example, let's consider a class called `ViewController`. We want to create `ViewController+Private.h` and `ViewController+Private2.h` that have additional `privateView` outlets, which will still be accessible within `ViewController.m`.

Here's how we can do it:

**ViewController.h**

```
// Nothing special here

#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface ViewController : UIViewController
// some public properties go here
@end
```

**ViewController+Private.h**

```
// Note that we import the public header file
#import "ViewController.h"

@interface ViewController()
@property (nonatomic, weak) IBOutlet UIView *privateView;
@end
```

**ViewController+Private2.h**

```
// Note again we import the public header file
#import "ViewController.h"

@interface ViewController()
@property (nonatomic, weak) IBOutlet UIView *privateView2;
@end
```

**ViewController.m**

```
// Here's where the magic is
// We import each of the class extensions in the implementation file
#import "ViewController.h"
#import "ViewController+Private.h"
#import "ViewController+Private2.h"

@implementation ViewController

// We can also setup a basic test to make sure it's working.
// Just also make sure your IBOutlets are actually hooked up in Interface Builder

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    self.privateView.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor];
    self.privateView2.backgroundColor = [UIColor greenColor];
}

@end
```

And that's how we can do it.

**Why Your Code Wasn't Working**

Most likely, you've probably mixed up the `#import` statements. To fix this,

1) Make sure that each `class extension` file imports the original class header (i.e. `ViewController.h`)

2) Make sure that the class implementation (i.e. `ViewController.m`) file imports each of the class extension headers.

3) Make sure the class header (i.e. `ViewController.h`) file ***doesn't*** import any of the class extension headers.

For reference, you can also checkout the Apple docs on [Customizing Existing Classes](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/cocoa/conceptual/ProgrammingWithObjectiveC/CustomizingExistingClasses/CustomizingExistingClasses.html).

Comment: I wasn't 100% sure about my original answer, so I checked it and found it to be incorrect. I've updated the answer with the correct info. :D

Comment: interesting.. i always wondered what the `()` meant.. whenever i saw that inside an m file, i figured it's just a way to user obj-c `@property` privately (ie it auto generates the accessors.. but for access within the .m file only)

Comment: @abbood, Yeah, the most common use of class extensions is to hide variables that you don't want publicly visible.. usually class extensions are indeed put in the class's implementation file. But hey, you can do it this way too. :D

Comment: would [object association](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/cocoa/reference/objcruntimeref/Reference/reference.html#//apple_ref/c/func/objc_setAssociatedObject) work here (ie for IBoutlets)?

Comment: @abbood, I thought about this too.. I don't think it would because object association sets the association via the runtime. Plus, you wouldn't actually be able to denote it as an `IBOutlet` within a category, AFAIK. If you can figure out a hack though, let me know. :D

Comment: I wanted to ask you something.. sometimes you'll see something like this in the .m file: @implementation ViewController {@private //define instance variables} what value does this `private` thing adds? private to who? aren't they already private considering that they're defined within the .m file?

Comment: oh bummer! so with class extensions I can only add instance variables/properties.. but methods must be implemented in the original .m file eh? (that's what the docs say)